# Clojure 1.9 command line tools - command not found clj.sh

Tags: clojure

I have just installed clojure 1.9 on my mac via Homebrew.

As expected  I get 2 links in `/usr/local/bin` to the actual executables

`clojure@ -> ../Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358/bin/clojure`

`clj@ -> ../Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358/bin/clj`

running clojure from the command line works

`$ clojure
Clojure 1.9.0
user=>`

but for not for the command line tools

`$ clj
zsh: command not found: clj.sh`

both executable files exist

`$ ls Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358/bin 
clj*     clojure*`

I've tried uninstalling clojure with `brew uninstall` and have deleted the cached version of `clojure-tools-1.9.0.358.tar.gz` in my `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/` directory.

Installing it again was successful

```
    $ brew install clojure
    ==> Downloading https://download.clojure.org/install/clojure-tools-1.9.0.358.tar.gz ####### 100.0%
    ==> ./install.sh /usr/local/Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358
      /usr/local/Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358: 9 files, 19.4MB, built in 31 seconds
```

but still the same error.

Interestingly if I use the Finder to locate the file and double click on it, a new terminal window opens up and things seem to work.

```
    Last login: Tue Mar  6 10:35:48 on ttys002
    /usr/local/Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358/bin/clj ; exit;                             
    $ /usr/local/Cellar/clojure/1.9.0.358/bin/clj ; exit;
    Clojure 1.9.0
    user=>
```

Any ideas please on why this executable won't run directly from the command line?

Many thanks

Comment: What does `which clj` return? Did you alias it in your bash config maybe?

Comment: Hurrah!! you cracked it
`$ which clj` returned  `clj: aliased to clj.sh`
I'd forgetten that I'd set up an alias in my `.zprofile` for clj ages ago.
I've commented out the alias and it works as expected.
Thank you

Comment: Try ```brew unlink clojure && brew link clojure```

Comment: Thanks @pankajdoharey, the alias in my shell profile was the problem though. @ClojureMostly suggestion of trying `which clj` identified the cause.
It's all working fine now

Comment: @magwitch Welcome

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I'd set up an alias for `clj` in my shell profile file which referenced a shell script called `clj.sh` that I'd written but which no longer exists - hence why nothing happened except an error message.
Removing the alias from the shell profile file corrected the problem.